# What is the simplest way to use svn repository through firewall without compromizing the security?

Tags: security, firewall, svn, tortoise-svn

I have a multiple Win xp/7 PCs in a network that have no Internet access. All traffic is routed through a firewall PC (latest ubuntu LTS, without admin). This firewall has limited ports open to Internet. The svn client has to be tortoise svn (users are mostly labview programmers).

What is the simplest way to use svn located in e.g. googlecode?

```
a) Mirror svn to firewall and maintain mirror scripts.

b) Pipe google repository through firewall and maintain pipe.

c) Network mount (samba, nfs, etc) of the disk of firewall pc.

d) Other solution where tortoise svn handles this automatically.

e) Something else that I have not thought about.
```

A, B and C above are something that I can do but what I don't want to do, because I have to maintain useless services (commits are once or twice a week).

C sounds promising if its possible. And D, all other ideas are welcome.

**edit:** The firewall blocks all access except ports 22 and 23.

**edit 2:** The system is essentially:

"computer without internet, ports 22,23 open" --> "firewall computer with internet" --> "googlecode svn"

**edit 3:** ok, It seems that its impossible to get this working with googlecode. Is there any free reliable online svn repositories with svn+ssh enabled?

**edit 4:** Got a solution (bad one though): I dropped open repositories from the equation and keep our repository inside the firewall. Code sharing is by request with zipped svn-repo. Original question still remains: Open svn+ssh repository + firewall = impossible? I will create another rephrased question from this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't just use the googlecode repository for the commits ? it uses https for the access so is secure and you will not have to deal with more services in your local network. If there is a need for a local copy of the repository, I would suggest git which is more appropiate for handling a local repository in your network that can later be uploaded to google code.

Comment: I can't access the googlecode repository directly because the firewall blocks the traffic (solution for this is B, which I don't want to maintain). git is out of the question because labview-coders cannot use it (to my knowledge lvmerge and lvdiff are meant to work only with svn, right?)

Comment: How about [ssh+svn](http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/setting-up-svn)?

Comment: If you don't use Web, why you have link and squid (http-proxy)?

Comment: @marcus-ekwall: GC support **only** http-repo

Comment: @Marcus: How do you do ssh+svn through a firewall-PC? I know only a solution that first creates an ssh-pipe and then uses ssh+svn... If you have more insight let me know.

Comment: @LazyBadger: Is squid similar to ssh-piping but with http? I.e. you install a third party program (=squid that essentially is a service) which pipes the traffic from local address to remote address. Good point with GC.

Comment: @Juha, like Lazy Badger said, GC doesn't support it. The only secure way to access GC is with SSL, but that traffic goes through port 993, which is closed?

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: yes, 993 is closed.

Comment: https is **not** 993 and usable over Squid. @Juha, if you have functional SQUID, why you have question about CG usage? Squid is **httpp-proxy**, SVN **uses pure http** for work. Where was troubles found?

Comment: @LazyBadger: I don't have SQUID and I don't want to install one unless I really really have to.

Comment: If you have to have commits **to** GC, you have to open http. Anyway... For RO you can `svn hotcopy` by a) method

Comment: > Is squid similar to ssh-piping but with http? Well, yes, in some degree

Comment: @Juha, LazyBadger corrected me once again hehe. I'm sorry for the wrong port number. What I should had said is that HTTPS uses port 443. Was meddling with securing IMAP (which uses 993) at the time, so mixed them up. Anyhow, why can't you just allow HTTPS traffic to googlecode's servers in your firewall?

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: company policy, no internet (http, https, etc.) for these kind of systems.

Comment: Just enable **one IP** for https. It's needed for work, not for jokes

Comment: @LazyBadger: Unfortunately, fighting with IT support about security issues and company policies is not an **easy solution**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any free reliable online svn repositories with svn+ssh enabled?

It was hard work to find even **non-free** [svn+ssh hosting](http://www.csoft.net/index.html.en)